# Finding output voltage of a MOSFET using its datasheet

Tags: mosfet, digital-logic, datasheet, nmos

Given a supply voltage of 4800 mV to a resistor loaded NMOS inverter with a single Nmosfet (2N7002) and a 6 ohm resistor, what would be the output voltage when the input voltage is 3500 mV?
How should I use the datasheet of 2N7002 mosfet to find output voltage for these conditions, exactly?

(I'm attaching the images of the 2N7002 datasheet. This is not a homework. I'm just trying to understand how to use a datasheet.)

Thanks for any ideas in advance!

[image: datasheet1]

[image: datasheet2]

[image: datasheet3]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwhpF6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: What are you really trying to do here? First look at Rds(ON) Max) right at teh top of your datasheet, and compare it with your 6 ohm load. That should tell you this is a terrible choice of MOSFET for the job. Then look at Fig 1 and read Id vs Vds for your chosen Vgs ... note Id maxes out about 0.25A. That tells you the voltage across your load. (NOTE the figures are "typical" ... don't be surprised if your actual Id is significantly different.

Comment: Read the tolerances for Vgs(th) and current at that threshold. You need at least 2.5x this worst case to get more precise RdsOn values to compute current.

Answer (score 1):

The mosfet will have approximately 4-5Ω (we can't be exact because of the current and other factors like manufacturing). Which means the voltage output will be around 2.6V to 2.8V. If an exact voltage is needed, then negative feedback will be needed to control the voltage.

Mosfets in open loop (no feedback) are typically used either in the fully off or fully on state. (also a good idea to prevent mosfets from burning up)

The mosfet will dissipate more than 1W in this condition which will be more than it's rated for and will burn up if operated in the circuit above.

The way to find out what the resistance of the mosfet is through this chart:

The resistance can be determined from the Gate to Source (Vgs) voltage. If you know what the voltage is then you can determine the resistance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Rds(ON) is also a function of temperature, so it varies a lot.
so you can't get a precise answer. Plus Id rating.....

[image: Rds(ON) vs T]

Comment: Please Note that this is a very high Rds. Today MOSFET 's Rds is in the hundreds of milliohms range.